# Extracting data from protect TXT file and turning it into a table via PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have some election data that's formatted in a text document and separated by commas that I'm trying to reformat for our website using PHP.

The text file is protected with a user name and password, so I'm trying to figure out how to extract the data into an array to manipulate. Here's the link (https://go.elections.hawaii.gov/media-results/files/summary.txt), but I pulled a sample of the data here for reference (http://lilly-digital.com/test/summary.txt).

Using the code below, I was able to produce this table, but I need to reorder and exclude some of the data: https://lilly-digital.com/test/parse.php Any suggestions on how to do that, too?

```
<?php

$filename = 'https://lilly-digital.com/test/summary.txt';

$the_big_array = []; 

if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
  while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
  {
    $the_big_array[] = $data;       
  }

  // Close the file
  fclose($h);
}

$build = '<table><tbody>';
foreach($the_big_array as $row)
{
$build .= '<tr>';
foreach($row as $item)
{
$build .= "<td>{$item}</td>";
}
$build .= '</tr>';
}
$build .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $build;

?>
```

In summary, any idea how to extract the data using the username and password and reformat the data? I'm relatively new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication code Used from **Ariful Islam**'s answer

```
$https_user = "user_name";
$https_password = "password";

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n".
      "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$https_user:$https_password")."\r\n",
    'content' => $body,
    'timeout' => 60
  )
);
```

Once authenticated, you should try **array_combine** function which will create an array with keys containing **fieldnames** and values containing **fielddata** for the Mysql table. The code will be like:

```
$fileUrl = 'https://lilly-digital.com/test/summary.txt';
$delimiter=',';
$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($fileUrl, 'r')) !== FALSE){
  while (($row = fgetcsv($handle,0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
  {
   if(!$header) 
     $header = $row;
   else 
    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
```

The output would be similar to following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Contest ID] => 2
            [Contest Title] => U.S. Representative, Dist I - D
            [Contest Seq Nbr] => 2
            [Contest Type] => OF
            [Contest Party] => 
            [Absentee Mail Blank Votes] => 0
            [Absentee Walk-in Blank Votes] => 0
            [Election Blank Votes] => 0
            [Absentee Mail Over Votes] => 0
            [Absentee Walk-in Over Votes] => 0
            [Election Over Votes] => 0
            [Registered Voters] => 795248
            [Total Precincts] => 115
            [Counted Precincts] => 0
            [Candidate ID] => 9
            [Candidate Name] => CASE, Ed
            [Candidate Seq Nbr] => 1
            [Candidate Party] => 
            [Absentee Mail Votes] => 0
            [Absentee Walk-in Votes] => 0
            [Election Votes] => 0
            [Total Votes] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array ... so on
```

To insert into the database, you need to use the following code

```
$fields = implode("','",$header);
$fields = "'".$fields."'";

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

$value = implode("','",$value);
$value = "'".$value."'";

 $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME ($fields) VALUES ($value)";
}
```

Note: It is highly recommended to use **Mysql Prepared statement**. You can use the above logic while implementing it.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but what would the authentication part look like with this example? I'm having having success pulling the data with authentication, but the method I'm using puts all the data in one array with one big string. I tried using EXPLODE to separate the string, but I'm having trouble with the commas and double quotes.

Comment: @DRog Please share what is the final output of the big string and share your existing authentication code too

Comment: Sure, this authentication code (https://lilly-digital.com/test/example-code.PNG) generates this data output in one big string (https://lilly-digital.com/test/example.php). Using `explode` (https://lilly-digital.com/test/example-2-code.PNG) breaks up the commas within the quotes, which is what I don't want (https://lilly-digital.com/test/example-2.php). I tried using `fgetcsv` (https://lilly-digital.com/test/example-3-code.PNG), but I may be using it wrong; it's not working (https://lilly-digital.com/test/example-3.php). I'm close, but obviously something's wrong with the code I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

Server is protected using [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/) so you need to pass a username and password along with the request. You can do that with [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)

```
$username='Roland';
$password='Orzabal';

$auth = base64_encode("$username:$password");
$header = array("Authorization: Basic $auth");
$opts = array( 'http' => array ('method'=>'GET', 'header'=>$header));
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
//stream context is ready

$filename = 'https://lilly-digital.com/test/summary.txt';

$the_big_array = [];
```

stream context is the last optional parameter in [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r", false, $context)) !== FALSE) 
{
    //stuff 
}

//other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
$https_user = "user_name";
$https_password = "password";

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n".
      "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$https_user:$https_password")."\r\n",
    'content' => $body,
    'timeout' => 60
  )
);

$https_server = 'https://lilly-digital.com/test/summary.txt';
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = $https_server;
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$line_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $result);

$final_result = array_map(function($val) {
    return explode(',', $val);
}, $line_array);
```

`$final_result` will represent a multi-dimensional array. Process this array as your need

Comment: The authentication works the way I need it to, but how do I process the data using "str_getcsv" instead of using `explode`? For example, this code seems to organize the data how I want it, but it doesn't work with the authentication example above.
`<?php
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
    array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
      $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
    });
    array_shift($csv); # remove column header
?>`